# C# - Multiple switch cases/statements vs Nested If

Tags: c#

I have a windows application with 3 listboxes. The user can choose one item from each listbox, and then get an output based on the specific combination of selected items.

I was initially using nested if statements for this, but would there be an easier way?

example for just two listboxes:

```
// if the first option in Vendors is chosen AND first option in Models is chosen
if (vendorListBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    if (modelListBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        outputTextBox.Text = "This is your answer";
    }
```

This code runs when a display button is clicked

Comment: are the options independent or do they depend on each other; what you do with the selections in say list 2 depend on the selection in list 1?

Comment: In this case Dannys example is ok but if you have more complex cases it would be a good idea to look at the new switch expressions with tuple pattern matching. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/may/csharp-8-0-pattern-matching-in-csharp-8-0

Comment: This really depends on how you lookup the answer to the combination.  Perhaps you could build a `Dictionary<String, String>` to hold the answers?  Then you concat the three options together as a key and lookup the answer in your Dictionary.  Without more details, the approach you're currently taking looks like it's going to be a huge mess.  How many combinations are we talking about here?...

Comment: Based on the sparse sample presented, where it appears that each vendor has it's own set of models, and each model should produce a different result, I'd say the way you have it is fine.

Comment: "an easier way" might be to store the data in a relational database and then use databinding to populate the controls.

Answer (score 2):

No need for ifs and switches.

I would use a lookup list with 3 integer values and a string for this, it allows for dynamic maintenance outside your code, e.g. in a database. Quick and dirty example..

```
List<Tuple<int,int,int, string>> PrepareLookupTable()
{
  var lst = new List<Tuple<int,int,int, string>>();
  lst.Add(new Tuple<int,int,int,string>(0,0,0,"Your answer"));
  lst.Add(new Tuple<int,int,int,string>(0,1,0,"Original answer"));
  lst.Add(new Tuple<int,int,int,string>(0,2,1,"Really rediculous answer"));
  // .. or fill the list from somewhere else database.. or json..
  return lst;
}

string ShowMessageForSelection(List<Tuple<int,int,int, string> lst)
{
  var sel1 = ListBox1.SelectedIndex;
  var sel2 = ListBox2.SelectedIndex;
  var sel3 = ListBox3.SelectedIndex;
  var t = lst.FirstOrDefault(x=>(sel1==Item1)&&(sel2==Item2)&&(sel3==Item3));
  if (t!=null) outputTextBox.Text = t.Item4;
 }

 // to use: 
 //    var lst = PrepareLookupTable();
 //    ShowMessageForSelection(lst);
```

Comment: But if you add/remove items, or sort them differently, then your integers will no longer be valid.  Why not just use `Tuple<string, string, string, string>` and lookup the items with the actual selections instead of the indices?...

Comment: Good idea Idle_Mind.. it would require a cast, that is var sel1 = (string)Listbox1.SelectedItem. In c# nothing else needs to be changed.

Comment: ...but if you're going to go through the trouble of doing it this way, I'd skip the `Tuple` in favor of a `Dictionary` as I suggested in the comments.  Then your lookup will be much faster.  You'd still put together the three items, but as a KEY so you can retrieve the VALUE.

Comment: .. and when the user is allowed to select more than 1 option in each box, typing should be refined anyway. It's only a quick and dirty example, as I stated. Of course, some explicit typing is better, my answer was intended to put a simple alternative for if's and switches.  It allows one to configure the combinations at runtime, or externally. Ifs and switches don't allow that,

Answer (score 1):

If you like it more, you can write combined conditions, so instead of

```
if(condition1){
    ...
    if(condition2){
        ...
```

you can do:

```
if(condition1 && condition2){
    ...
```

Comment: It might be noted that if each vendor has multiple models, combining the conditions will reduce performance, as there will be an evaluation done for every model of every vendor until the correct combination is found, whereas in the original sample there is only one evaluation for each vendor until the correct vendor is found, and only then are the models for that vendor evaluated.