# How to format code with multiple listbox combinations

Tags: c#

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63076293/205233) a few days ago and got some great feedback but I want to provide more context to what I am doing.

I have 3 listboxes, each of which will likely have 10+ options. The user selects some combination of options (1 option in each textbox). Based on that, a specific output gets displayed.

What I have now is just nested if statements. While this works, I feel like it will get messy fast. I have only done it for the first options in each test box

```
 private void displayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (scriptGenButton.Checked)
        {
            // if the first option in Vendors is chosen AND first option in Models is chosen AND first option in Options is chosen
            if (vendorListBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                if (modelListBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    if (optionListBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        outputTextBox.Text = "Option1!";
                    }
                }
            }
```

How would you guys approach it in this scenario? I know some people mentioned dictionaries.

Comment: Use `&&` instead of nested if?!? - this seems like a good read: https://kodify.net/csharp/if-else/if-logical-operators/

Comment: What version of the language do you use? Is pattern matching available to you?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov how can I check that for you? I am using visual studio 2019

Comment: @RandRandom that looks more efficient! Reading that now

Comment: Are you using .NET Core or .NET Framework?

Comment: .NET Framework @AlexanderPetrov

Comment: Very sorry. In .NET Core, there is a version of C# 8 available, in which your task is solved very elegantly. | In the .NET Framework only version C# 7.3 is available

Answer (score 1):

Don't use nested ifs like that, use the && operator.

```
if(scriptGenButton.Checked && vendorListBox.SelectedIndex == 0 && modelListBox.SelectedIndex == 0 && ...) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can offer the following solution. Add values to the tuple. And then compare the tuples.

```
var values = (scriptGenButton.Checked, vendorListBoxSelected.Index, modelListBoxSelected.Index, optionListBoxSelected.Index);

if (values == (true, 0, 0, 0))
{
    outputTextBox.Text = "Option1!";
}
else if (values == (true, 0, 0, 1))
{
    outputTextBox.Text = "Option2!";
}
// and so on
```

Comment: This is amazing. Simple and I can understand why it works... thank you so much!